# Android webview has white border around it and how can i get rid of it?

Tags: android, web, webview, android-webview

I have a android app using a webview to load a webpage, however in the graphical layout and in the app it shows a white thick border, I tried resizing and I tried changing the width and height in the XML layout file, but no change. Please check the below image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This white border that you can see might be just from the background of the layout container of the webview. Please make sure that you don't have a padding on the layout or margin on the webview.

Comment: Thanks, the layout margins were defined in `res/values/dimens.xml` by default.

Comment: dimens.xml padding was set to 16dp should be 0dp: `<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
</resources>`

Answer (score 15):

This seems to work for me:

```
String frameString = "<html><body style='margin:0;padding:0;'><iframe src=\"http://k-video.com/\" height=\"410\" width=\"320\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 11):

Try to modify your HTML content like this:

```
<body style='margin:0;padding:0;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color of your `WebView` with `webview.setBackgroundColor()`.

I set my `WebView` background either transparent (invisible) and white with the following function:

```
private void setWebviewTransparency(final boolean transparent) {
    final int color = transparent ? 0 : Color.WHITE;
    webview.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

This color will only work in the field area if your web page source does not specify background color. If the page source *does* specify background, then this color will only affect the padding area correctly addressed by @Marcin.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
   <body style='margin:0;padding:0;'>
     <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$mVideoId" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

In **mVideoId** replace with your youtube videoId

Above iframe string working for me for playing youtube video without margin and padding.

Answer (score -3):

Right click on the WebView and click remove container. Its that simple!

Comment: This solved my problem. I was so depressed. Thank you for giving me that smile:)